# how to get the value of <input type=" text"> in html

Tags: html, css

This is the code I used to create frames but not able to do so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>MATERIALS</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link href="projectstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body link="blue" vlink="purple" alink="red" background="" bgcolor="#90EE90" text="white">
<frameset cols="50%,*">
<frame src="file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/WEB/frame2.html" />
<frame src="file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/WEB/frame1.html" />
</frameset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: +1 - How specifically does the title of your post relate to your supplied mark-up. There appear to be no inputs elements in your example...

Answer (score 0):

The frameset tag does not work inside the body tag.Remove the body tag and it should work.Also you can use just "frame1.html" and "frame2.html" as src attribute of the frames if you are keeping them in the same folder instead of using their full address.

Here is the Code which worked for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>MATERIALS</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link href="projectstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<frameset cols="50%,*">
<frame src="frame2.html" />
<frame src="frame1.html" />
</frameset>
</html>
```